# How can I create dynamic CONTAO pages?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, contao

So I'm developing this website on CONTAO CMS and I have many information in database tables created by me. [eg: I have database table named Country with 2000 records in it].

Then in CONTAO I have the page called Record (alias: record.html) in which I want to display information about one record at a time (depending on which one was requested).
I thought of something like this http://path.com/to/my/page/record.html?id=201 and the information displayed should be of the 201st record in the table.

The problem is that I don't know how to achieve that in CONTAO.

I also used this CONTAO insert tag: {{file::myfile.php?id='someid'}}. It works, in myfile.php i get the someid and query the database for the information needed. The problem of this solution is that I don't know how to pass the ID from the browser URL inside this CONTAO TAG.

Looking forward to any solutions you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your issue correctly, this is the solution to it:

```
$recordId = Input::get('id');
```

Source: http://api.contao.org/classes/Contao.Input.html

Comment: I did found out about this functionality of Contao but I didn't knew hot to use it, now I tried to use it in way it didn't seem logic for me and SURPRISE, it works! I foud my solution! Thanks a lot!